# How to use dynamic column names in DolphinDB sqlColAlias function?

Tags: dolphindb

For example, the code I currently have:

```
keycol = `Testcol
led = 5
sql(select=(sqlCol("*"), sql(sqlColAlias(<sma(keycol, led)>, keycol + '_5)), from=tbm)
// <select *, sma(keycol, led) as Testcol5 from tbm>
// wanted, <select *, sma(TestCol, 5) as TestCol5 from tbm>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `makecall()` function in DolphinDB to call a function with specified parameters to generate a piece of the script here. For example,

```
sqlColAlias(makecall(sma, sqlCol(keycol), led), keycol + "_5")
```